# Can't access API that's on a local linux server externally

Tags: linux, api, debian

I've come here as a last resort, I have a Windows machine installed on it is Oracle VB with Debian 12 VM on it that I use to run an API on.

When I try to access the API on the Linux server using **10.0.2.15:8000** it works fine and the API responds as expected.

So I made a port forwarding on Oracle (I am using a NAT adapter) to forward from **127.0.0.1:2022** the Windows host to **10.0.2.15:8000** the API on the Linux server.

Then I tried to connect to the API from my Windows machine using **127.0.0.1:2022** but it didn't work it kept on loading but nothing appears.

**Note**:

- I use the same concept (port forwarding) to connect from my Windows machine to the Linux server using SSH and it works perfectly so idk why this is happening
- I start the API using `uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 app.main:app` so it should listen to any IP
- I've set the CORS origins to `origins = ["*"]` so it should allow any origin

[image: Port Forwarding window]

[image: CORS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok...
I've been trying to solve this problem for the past 4 days and it turned out that the problem was with the firewall on Linux.

If anyone faces the same problem, run these commands.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport {port_number} -j ACCEPT


sudo ufw allow {port_number}


sudo firewall-cmd --add-port={port_number}/tcp --permanent
```

Replace **{port_number}** with the port you wanna use. Also remove the curly brackets.